# I had dual boot ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had dual boot ubuntu on laptop which already had windows 10 installed.
Ubuntu had installed correctly and grub loader screen had come.
it shows options for ubuntu and windows.
windows options works correctly and boot to windows but
the ubuntu option does not respond when I select the ubuntu the only purple screen appears and capslock key keeps on blinking.
nothing else is happening

Comment: I'm Unsure whether this problem is related to Ubuntu, I basically depends on your mother-board.Now just click you power button (Turn it off), then power it back (turn it on). Now click on Ubuntu from you grub boot-loader. Don't "hibernate" in windows

Comment: I had done this a lot of times but the same thing happens

Comment: Once try to re-install grub